# Using Spring SAML as an IDP rather than an SP

Tags: java, spring, saml, spring-saml

Are you able to use Spring SAML if you are implementing as an IDP?

I have used it in the past when acting as a Service Provider, and having read the documentation its not clear on whether I can use it as an IDP.

Note - I originally asked for opinions on another question which was put on hold by Users, I reworded the question as above but its still on hold hence I have asked again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no support for acting as an IDP in Spring SAML. Capabilities of Spring SAML are described in the manual:

> "The extension enables both new and existing applications to act as a
>   Service Provider in federations based on Web Single Sign-On and Single
>   Logout profiles of SAML 2.0 protocol."

For implementing SAML 2.0 IDP using open source tools have a look at for example [Shibboleth](https://www.shibboleth.net/products/identity-provider/).

Comment: Looks like the link is dead.