# Identity Provider Implementation with SAML V2 and Java

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, idp

After successfully implementing **SAML-V2 Service Provider (SP)**; for supporting some specific use-case, I have to implement my own **SAML-2 IdP**. After going through [OASIS Documentation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0.html) and many others about the SAML protocol, I have started implementing it.

- My Use-case is just a single profile (`Web Browser SSO Profile`) with  `SP-Initiated SSO: Redirect Bindings` only.

I am looking for some lean third-party library or java based implementation which I can refer/use to speed up the implementation and customize on top of that.

**Would love for any recommendation or suggestion in this direction.**

To be specific I'm looking for any/all of below :

- Easy to use open-source library for implementing SAML-V2 Identity Provider in Java.
- Detailed documentation/specification for above profile.
- Any advice from experts who have past experience in implementation such kind of IdP.

---

There is lots of material available for SP. However, very few and complex for IdP. 
Some of the java-based implementation which I am already looking are : [KeyCloak](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak) and [Lite-IdP](https://github.com/amdonov/lite-idp).

Comment: Implementing a SAMLv2 compliant IdP is quite some effort. You might even do a compliance test. I wonder why you can not use an existing one, even a free of charge one.

Answer (score 1):

"Very few and complex" is true because building a real-world identity provider is a serious project. [OpenSAML](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OS30/Home) as the library is your best option in Java - many enterprise-grade implementations that we know about are built with it. A good, stripped-down example of how to use OpenSAML in IdP context is https://github.com/OpenConext/Mujina .

Lite IdP is written in Go. If you're open to non-Java options, [SimpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/) is excellent, it's certainly better documented than many others.

Answer (score 0):

I'd post it as comment, but I don't have enough reputation.
But here you have almost the same question, regarding Spring SAML:
[using-spring-saml-as-an-idp-rather-than-an-sp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979525/using-spring-saml-as-an-idp-rather-than-an-sp)

Take a look at Vladimir's answer, I think it's what you're looking for. [Here is the link](https://www.shibboleth.net/products/identity-provider/) suggested by him.

Cheers